# Calling javascript functions from html code that I inject

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a javascript and injecting it via a chrome extension such as Tamper Monkey.
I find all the tags and then change it to a button but I am not able to make the click work. My page has some text called "Approver". I replace that with a button with the same text "Approver" and it shows as a button, but when I click it, the function ptmTest is not getting called. Below is part of the Javascript code that I am using to try and make this work. Any help on what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

```js
function ptmButton() {
  var x         = document.querySelectorAll( "dt" );
  var ptmButton = `<button class="aui-buttons trigger-label" onClick="ptmTest()">Approver</button>`
  var i;
  for ( i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
    if ( x[i].innerText == "Approver" ) {
      x[i].innerHTML = ptmButton;
    }
  }

  function ptmTest() {
    console.log( "PTM clicked" )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

you can put the function ptmTest outside ptmButton:

```
function ptmButton() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll( "dt" );
    var ptmButton = `<button class="aui-buttons trigger-label">Approver</button>`
    var i;
    for ( i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
        if ( x[i].innerText == "Approver" ) {

            x[i].innerHTML =
                ptmButton;
        }
    }

}

function ptmTest() {
    console.log( "PTM clicked" )
}
```

you can also set the onClick in the script:

```
function ptmButton() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll( "dt" );
    var ptmButton = `<button class="aui-buttons trigger-label" onClick="ptmTest()">Approver</button>`
    var i;
    for ( i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
        if ( x[i].innerText == "Approver" ) {

            x[i].innerHTML =
                ptmButton;
            x[i].children[0].onclick = (e)=> {
                ptmTest();
            }
        }
    }

    function ptmTest() {
        console.log( "PTM clicked" )
    }
}
```